# Pagination in PHP during passing a value at the first time when the page loads

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

This is a simple code which I am using in PHP. But the problem is every time I run the page, it says undefined index page. But after clicking a href link, it works perfectly. Can anyone help me out how to resolve the error?

Actually the `$_GET['page']` isn't having a value at the first time when the page loads. But I need this to execute the query to take out data from the database. Here's the code:

```
<?php

require 'db_connect.php';

$page=$_GET["page"];
if($page=="" || $page=="1") {
    $page1=0;
} else {
    $page1=($page*5)-5;
}


$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE deletion_status=1 limit $page1,5";
$res=mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['product_id']." ".$row['product_name'];
    echo "<br>";
}

$sql1="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE deletion_status=1";
$res1=mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql1);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($res1);
echo'<br>';
//echo $count;
$a=$count/5;
echo'<br>';
$a=ceil($a);

for($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++){
    ?><a href="pagination2.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>" style="text-decoration: none;"><?php echo " "; echo $b;?></a><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface exists is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to use the value, check if it exists:

```
$page = "1";
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
```

That way it's initialized with a default value, but if a value has been provided it will use that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check whether `$_GET['page']` is set or not, and assign the initial `$page` value accordingly.

So change `$page=$_GET["page"];` to

```
$page=isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : "1";
```